# UITableViewCell & iPhone OS 2.2.1

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

How can I add on a Cell few UILabels and UIButton? My limit it's app should support OS start from 2.2.1.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](http://www.cocoacast.com/?q=node/182) great tutorial on how to use Interface Builder to custom build your UITableCellView objects. You won't regret it.